# How to switch workspace via the Unity Desktop ICON via Mouse Wheel Specifically

Tags: 12.04, unity, 14.04, mouse, workspace-switcher

I want to **wheel over** the "Workspace Icon" in the Unity Switcher to change desktops. (I know you can switch workspaces via COMPIZ which is ok for wheeling the desktop), but I would like to wheel over the Unity Switcher Icon to switch workspaces.

Lubuntu, Kubuntu, and Xubuntu all allow you to wheelover the Workspace Icon to change desktops, Can Unity's Icon be configured to do the same?

**Can this be done with Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 and the New Unity? The Mouse wheel is critical for workspaces for me. Anyone know?**

Comment: I think I could make a bash script that could do something like this, but it wouldn't be perfect. No other way of doing this I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Man, I wish it would have been possible to use Mouseover on the Unity Workspace switcher :(

Comment: Can you reccomend the steps required to modify the launcher's wheelover function to enable it to switch workspaces?

Comment: The best you're going to get is a bash script I'm afraid.